# for (id obj in studentArray) only iterating through first item in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

The below is suppose to run through a `NSMutableArray` of `*Students` with an `address` property. But for some reason the for isn't iterating through the entire `NSMutableArray`, only the first object.

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    for (id obj in studentArray) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[Student class]]) {
            Student *selectedStudent = obj;
            [geocoder geocodeAddressString:selectedStudent.address completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
                {
                    NSString *latDest1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude];
                    NSString *lngDest1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude];
                    NSLog(@"%@, %@",latDest1, lngDest1);
                }
            }];
        }
    }
```

Any Ideas what I could be doing wrong? The app doesn't crash, just simply checks one of 4 students in the array.
Thanks

Comment: What does using breakpoints and stepping in the debugger show you?

Comment: @CRD the app doesn't crash, just simply outputs 1 set of coordinates in the log instead of 4 (there are 4 students in the array)

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the start of the above code, When the debugger stops there examine the variable values and then step through. You'll probably want to add a breakpoint in the block as well, you can't step into that. Whatever the issue is will probably be apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like geocoding does not return placemarks for the next Student objects. The problem may be because of too much of geocode requests.
From the Apple documentation about Geocoding:

> After initiating a forward-geocoding request, do not attempt to
>   initiate another forward- or reverse-geocoding request. Geocoding
>   requests are rate-limited for each app, so making too many requests in
>   a short period of time may cause some of the requests to fail. When
>   the maximum rate is exceeded, the geocoder passes an error object with
>   the value network to your completion handler.

Comment: I.e. it is an asynchronous method that you must ensure that only one is in flight.  OP's code ignores the error returned by subsequent calls which is why it fails transparently.